# information oracle version c#

Tags: c#, oracle

I have oracle(one or more)install on the machine.
I want to know how I can to get information about the version of oracle 
and also if it client or server etc.
I can not use the name of oracle because it can to change b y user etc.
I think to use of files in bin folder execute them and use the informationin the output.
someone can to help me and direct me?
thanks a lot!!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'client or server'.  Please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT banner FROM v$version WHERE banner LIKE 'Oracle%';
```

This should give edition, version and bitness.

From http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/sql-injection/oracle-sql-injection-cheat-sheet

Comment: I try it but when I execute it in oracle I get the following error:ORA-00911: invalid character
00911. 00000 -  "invalid character"
*Cause:    identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
 letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
(q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL

Comment: I have to ask - did you put v$version or $version?

Comment: Oh - also, try removing the trailing semicolon for immediately executed queries.

Comment: can I get in a similar way the oracle_home?

Comment: on my machine installed 2 oracles.and when I run the following:SELECT banner FROM v$version WHERE banner LIKE 'Oracle%';I get only one of them.How can I get the both?

Answer (score 1):

select * from v$version where banner like ‘Oracle%’;

Answer (score 1):

if you are refering to the binaries instead of the database (which may not be present), check $ORACLE_home/inventory/response. there should be a file like `oracle.something.rsp`. the something will describe the install eg:
`oracle.client_Runtime.rsp` (if you installed the client - runtime option) or `oracle.server_EE.rsp` is its a server enterprise build. grep out TOPLEVEL in that file for the version.
eg on a server enterprise build:

```
$ cat oracle.server_EE.rsp | grep TOPLEVEL | grep -v "#"
TOPLEVEL_COMPONENT={"oracle.server","11.2.0.1.0"}
so its a server installation (EE) = 11.2.0.1.0.
```